# Translating "insurance deductible"?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

What is best or correct way to translate `insurance deductible`?

- deducible de seguro
- tiene de deducible

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, the English article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deductible is linked to the Spanish one http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deducible. So you can just say:

> deducible

or

> franquicia

I did some research on "deducible" and "franquicia" in Spanish and it does match this meaning: the money you have to pay before the insurance starts covering any cost. You have an accident and for example, the first 600 euros of reparations are covered by you. The rest, by the insurance company.

For example in http://www.pacificoseguros.com/site/conociendodeseguros/Autos/-Qu%C3%A9-es-el-deducible-o-franquicia.aspx

> Es el monto mínimo o porcentaje de los gastos que se encuentran
>   amparados por la póliza, que le corresponde pagar al asegurado por el
>   derecho de atención del siniestro. Ambos términos significan lo mismo
>   y suelen ser utilizados indistintamente.

Comment: +1, aunque creo que cada una tiene sus propias connotaciones, siendo la _franquicia_ una suma fija estipulada al momento de contratar el seguro mientras que el _deducible_ es un porcentaje del coste del daño a cubrir. Creo que incluso se puede volver más complicado dependiendo del seguro y tener [franquicia deducible y franquicia pura o no deducible](http://www.mapfre.es/wdiccionario/terminos/vertermino.shtml?f/franquicia.htm)

Answer (score 3):

- Deducible de poliza de seguro o Deducible de seguro.
- Franquicia: Esta palabra no corresponde ya que tienen diferente significado. Esta se puede referir a: Yo soy el propietario de una Franquicia de Dollar General o Starbucks por ejemplo.

http://www.crecenegocios.com/definicion-de-franquicia/

Comment: Parece ser, por el [link aportado por fedorqui](http://www.pacificoseguros.com/site/conociendodeseguros/Autos/-Qu%C3%A9-es-el-deducible-o-franquicia.aspx) que sí se usa "franquicia" en este contexto: "¿Qué es el deducible o franquicia? [...] **Ambos términos significan lo mismo y suelen ser utilizados indistintamente**. "

Comment: Por experiencia propia puedo decir que si se usa franquicia. La franquicia es el dinero que tiene que poner el asegurado antes de que empiece a cubrir el seguro.